Python Chess Engine: How do I replace the piece thats on the inputted square with a "#"?
When the user inputs a coordinate like "a1", I want to find the piece that is on that square and replace its icon with a "#" character and render the new board. So the rook in the new board should be a "#" symbol.
#IMPORTS
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
##END

# IMPORT C/C++ MODULE FOR GAME TITLE
lib = ctypes.CDLL('./c_title_module.so')
lib.c_title_module.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
title = lib.c_title_module()
title_str = title.decode('utf-8')
##END

#THE TITLE IMPORTED FROM C FILE.
print(title_str, "\n\n")

#PIECES FOR BLACK
piecesB = ["♜", "♞", "♝", "♛", "♚", "♝", "♞", "♜"]
pawnsB = ["♟︎", "♟︎", "♟︎", "♟︎", "♟︎", "♟︎", "♟︎", "♟︎"]
##END

#PIECES FOR WHITE
piecesW = ["♖", "♘", "♗", "♕", "♔", "♗", "♘", "♖"]
pawnsW = ["♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙", "♙"]
##END

#RAW CHESS BOARD
r1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1"]
r2 = ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2"]
r3 = ["a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3", "g3", "h3"]
r4 = ["a4", "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4", "h4"]
r5 = ["a5", "b5", "c5", "d5", "e5", "f5", "g5", "h5"]
r6 = ["a6", "b6", "c6", "d6", "e6", "f6", "g6", "h6"]
r7 = ["a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7"]
r8 = ["a8", "b8", "c8", "d8", "e8", "f8", "g8", "h8"]
##END

#FIND THE PIECE ON THE GIVEN SQUARE.
def find_piece(square, board):
    for idx, row in enumerate(board):
        if square in row:
            piece_idx = row.index(square)
            if idx < 2:  # If it's a black piece
                print(board[idx][piece_idx])  # Print the piece
                board[idx][piece_idx] = "#"  # Replace with "#"
                return board[idx][piece_idx]
            elif idx > 5:  # If it's a white piece
                print(board[idx][piece_idx])  # Print the piece
                return board[idx][piece_idx]
            else:
                return ""  # Empty square
    return ""

def board_display(board):
    for row in board:
        if "#" in row:
            # Replace "#" with the original pieces before displaying
            row = ["#" if square == "#" else square for square in row]
        print(" ".join(row))

def move(board):
    board_display(board)
    piece_initial = input("Move Piece On Square: ")
    piece = find_piece(piece_initial, board)
    if piece:
        print("Piece on square", piece_initial, ":", piece)
    piece_final = input(f"Move piece on square '{piece_initial}', to square: ")
    piece_2 = find_piece(piece_final, board)
    return board  # Return the updated board

# Define the initial state of the board
board = [
    piecesW,
    pawnsW,
    ["#" for _ in range(8)],
    ["#" for _ in range(8)],
    ["#" for _ in range(8)],
    ["#" for _ in range(8)],
    pawnsB,
    piecesB
]

while True:
    print("Current Board Setup: ")
    board = move(board)  # Update the board with the move






Expecting the piece on the inputted square to be replaced with a "#" character the next time the board is displayed. Right now nothing happens.

Probably due to the if square in row line below:
def find_piece(square, board):
    for idx, row in enumerate(board):
        if square in row: # Square == "b2", but row is filled with "#" or piece symbols
            pass


Say I entered "b2" value for the square. Since you are enumerating over the board, which only contains # or piece symbols, the square in row condition will always be false.
